# php rss reader does not show all child tag of item tag

Tags: php, xml

I tried to show all tag name and contents inside item tag of a rss.xml file.
Look at the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
            $xml=simplexml_load_file("rss.xml");    


            foreach($xml->channel->item as $item){

                foreach ($item->children() as $value) {
                    echo $value->getName() . ": " . $value . "<br>";
                }                         

            }

        ?> 
    </body>


<html>
```

This code works properly . But there is a tag like

```
   <content:encoded>.....</content:encoded>
```

inside item tag of rss.xml. I can't see this tag name and contents . Is there any way to show the tag name and contents ?

Comment: can you post a link to your rss file so i can test it?

Comment: sure:    http://www.prothom-alo.com/rss2.0/

Comment: Can you try put `print_r($value)` to see how eleemnt would read?

Comment: print_r($value) also skip <content:encoded>.....</content:encoded> tag

Comment: That's because `<content:encoded>` is an element in another namespace called `content`. See here for a way to read such elements: http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=302

Comment: Thanks for the namespace trick that’s exactly what I was looking for!